# does "app_key" means the same as "app_code" for HERE geocoding credentials on Python?

Tags: here-api

I am trying to geocode some addresses with python
so I created a freemium account on https://developer.here.com
my code is this

```
(...)
here = Here(here_config.app_id, here_config.app_code, timeout=5)
here.geocode(string_to_geocode)
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

my doubt comes from the difference between the terms *"app_code"* on my code sample and *"app_key"* on my credential screen.
Is there another step I need to do in order to get a *"app_code"* or is my *"app_key"* already supposed to be it?

P.S. on that same screen Here provides me an option of getting JAVASCRIPT keys, HERE SDK FOR IOS (PREMIUM EDITION) [this option cleary has a button that says "generate app_key and app_code", however, I am not developing a cellphone app, but a python program.
What am I missing ?

[here_credential_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geDGU.png)

Answer (score 3):

App ID and App Code have been replaced. We encourage all users to switch to API Key or OAuth 2.0 (JSON Web Tokens) authentication. Please be aware that as part of adapting to the new authentication method, some endpoints have also changed. 
please check the new domains [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/hosts-mapping.html)

You can either use your **ApiKey** or **App_Id/App_Code**.

for example like this-

```
https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}&searchtext=425+W+Randolph+Chicago
```

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-geocode.html

Comment: it worked, sorry for taking it so long to answer, I read that doc and it worked.